# Android studio deleted my mapsactivity.java How to recover?

Tags: java, android

I am making an app on android studios. I open my project to see that mapactivity.java is there but all the code inside of the .java file is gone. It's empty.

There was an error saying Content is not allowed in prolog. in workspace.xml.

Everything else is still intact. Please help me recover

Comment: We can't help you recover. Try recovery software or Time Capsule (only if you have one & you're using Mac)

Comment: try to check file history, if file was not deleted but updated then you should be able to find content in history

Comment: Did you create the project with git? If yes, it's easy to find any history back.

Answer (score 0):

to recover, decompile your app-debug-unaligned.apk file found in app/build/output/apk. When you decompile this, youll get your source code from the last time you compiled. Try apk decompiling sites like http://www.javadecompilers.com/

All the best